# Storing many images in Assets - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been using CloudKit to store images. Pulling images down from the cloud has been working all right, except now when I'm trying to load a table that has an image in each cell. It takes way too long. My question is, how many images can I acceptably store locally as `Assets`? My hope would be to have 50-100. So far, these images range from 45KB to 116KB. Should I really be using Core Data, or is Assets commonly considered ok for this sort of thing?

Comment: Assets is for fixed images you wish to supply with your app so they exist immediately as part of the app when downloaded from the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

50-100 100KB images are acceptable in Assets. And it's better create folders in assets to classify them.